# Could not iterate over Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type User = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  jp: string;
  };

  export function UserList(users: User[]) {
  return (
    <div>
      {users?.map((user) => {
        <div></div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

On above code I tried to Iterate over User array.But It gives me the following error even though the users variable is Array

```
  users.map is not a function
```

Comment: Then `users` may not be the array.

Comment: Do a check that users is an array. You're also not returning anything . Don't forget the return . return <div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Your type is User, why do you use Users[] and not User[] ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake made the change